# sql create a view combining two tables

Tags: mysql, view

```
Table 1

id DATE column1 column2
```

.

```
Table 2

id DATE column1 column2
```

The output I want is:

```
DATE {column1 from Table 1} {column2 from Table 2}
```

Obviously the DATE column is common for the two tables, the data from column1 & column2 differs
I tried with create view and union from the two tables but the result is that it combines {column1 from Table 1} and {column2 from Table 2} into one column while what i want is these two to be created as two seperate columns

Comment: Can you add to your post the exact SQL you were using to create the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is a simple `join`.

```
create view yourview as
  select t1.date, t1.column1, t2.column2
    from table1 t1
      inner join table2 t2
        on t1.date = t2.date
```

This assumes that you want column 1 from table1, column 2 from table2, where they share a common date.